# Out-of-sample likelihood example

Tags: likelihood, out-of-sample

I'm an amateur in statistics. I was reading a paper in which it is mentioned that

> A model gives high out-of-sample likelihood.

What does that mean? What is exactly "High-out-of-sample likelihood"? What would be the simple explaination of it?

Comment: Can you link to the paper?

Comment: http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf

Comment: 2nd sentence in a section 2. "Neural Model"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other folks who might have an answer, the relevant quote from the paper is as follows:

> The objective is to learn a good model $f(w_{t} ,\dots ,w_{t−n+1}) = \hat{P}(w_t|w_{t−1})$, in the sense that it gives high out-of-sample likelihood

After skimming the relevant section of the paper you linked, I think you could rephrase the author's comment (in plain English, avoiding stats jargon as much as possible) as follows:

> *"A good model is one that is consistent with the data we actually observe"*

Two important concepts to understand here.

- **Training data vs. real-world (out-of-sample) data**:

  - Training data is used to fit the model initially.  That's different from the the 'real-world' data you really need the model to handle.  *The author seems to be referring to this **real-world data** when he/she uses the term **out-of-sample data***.
- **Likelihood**:

  - When fitting a model, you want to know "how plausible is this model?".  To fit the model, you maximize this "plausibility", which is represented by the **likelihood** of seeing the data, given the model.
  - This is a tricky concept - it's not the likelihood of the model being "right", but is still a measure of how well the data "matches" the model.

So the author is saying that we want to learn a "good model" in the sense that it *is the most plausible model* for the *real world data we encounter*.